# Rails - authorization based on subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I need to limit the content available to a user based on there subscriptions.
Which rail authorization plugin will be best ?

I normally use declarative authorization but I dont think it is suited to this task.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: why not keep with declarative authorization? it is a solid piece of code.

Comment: I think I might be missing something, is it possible to do the following in declarative authorization. user 1 is allowed to access subscriptions - history, maths, science and user 2 is allowed to access subscription - history only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you. For the same reason, I am using [cancan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) now as it is really flexible and requires me less time to mess around.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

[Fat Model Auth](https://github.com/brentgreeff/fat_model_auth)

Its very flexable.

I think you might need a level of logic above any plugin.
I would define a subscription model, (you probably already have one),
then I would define which resources are available to a subscription.
You might want to put this in the db if you think it will change a lot.